# Getting all shared files and folders from a given site

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

Is it possible to get all files or folders that has been shared from a site in one batch, or do you need to iterate each single file and folder on the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use audit log to get all shared files and folders.

Go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Security -> Search -> Audit log search -> Shared file, folder, or site -> Add site address in the "File, folder, or site" section.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, not a bad solution. Appreciated. Can I get those logs using this API if you want to automate it? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference